# Shapefile to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, geometry, shapefile

Is there any C# library or code that I can use to upload data into SQL Server?

Once the table is created I need to append the columns from a shapefile into a database table. I am reading shapefile using [easygisdotnet library](http://www.easygisdotnet.com/) but I am not finding any help to convert Shape data into `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry`.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14797/use-arcgis-with-sql-server-2008-as-a-backend. I recommend you look at this stackexchange for the what you need,

Comment: @gh9 i don't think it is answer to my question.

Comment: not the answer to your question but it seems to be the best place to find one. It seems to be a stackexchange just for gis so it would make sense that they would have the experts that you need.

Comment: YOU CAN USE ogr2ogr -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:server=myinstance;database=dbname;trusted_connection=yes" nameof.shp      YOU CAN FIND C# BINDINGS ON GDAL WEBSITE

Answer (score 1):

[shp2sqlserver](http://code.google.com/p/cumberland/wiki/shp2sqlserver) (part of [cumberland](http://code.google.com/p/cumberland/), a .Net Spatial framework) is a command line tool for loading shapefiles into Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Just [checkout](http://code.google.com/p/cumberland/source/checkout) the source code.